# Can we pass parameters to the test cases functions in C++ using CppUnit?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testcase

I am using cppunit for testing my c++ code. I have written my test fixture like this

```
class MainTestFixture : public TestFixture
{
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(MainTestFixture);    
    CPPUNIT_TEST(Addition);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(Multiply);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

public: 
    void setUp(void);
    void tearDown(void);
protected:
    // Test Functions 
    void Addition(void);
    void Multiply(void);
};
```

Now if I implement test cases like

```
void MainTestFixture::Addition()
{
    // CPPUNIT_ASSERT(condition);
}
void MainTestFixture::Multiply()
{
    // CPPUNIT_ASSERT(condition);
}
```

**In the above code, is it possible that I pass parameters to Addition and Multiply functions?**

Where as I have made a suite for running this fixture like below

```
#include "MainTestFixture.h"

CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(MainTestFixture);

using namespace CPPUNIT_NS;
int main()
{
    // informs test-listener about testresults
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestResult testresult;

    // register listener for collecting the test-results
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestResultCollector collectedresults;
    testresult.addListener (&collectedresults);

    // register listener for per-test progress output
    CPPUNIT_NS::BriefTestProgressListener progress;
    testresult.addListener (&progress);

    // insert test-suite at test-runner by registry
    CPPUNIT_NS::TestRunner testrunner;
    testrunner.addTest (CPPUNIT_NS::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest ());
    testrunner.run(testresult);

    // output results in compiler-format
    CPPUNIT_NS::CompilerOutputter compileroutputter(&collectedresults, std::cerr);
    compileroutputter.write ();

    // Output XML for Jenkins CPPunit plugin
    ofstream xmlFileOut("cppMainUnitTest.xml");
    XmlOutputter xmlOut(&collectedresults, xmlFileOut);
    xmlOut.write();

    // return 0 if tests were successful
    return collectedresults.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: If you want testing with parameters the Google C++ Testing Framework (https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Type-Parameterized_Tests) offers such feature if you are willing to give it a try.

Comment: But my project also run on Linux, cppunit work well there. Will Google C++ work in linux?

Comment: gtest is multi-platform and works perfectly fine on Linux (I've used it many times). It also doesn't need to be installed (in fact the official recommendation is NOT to install it) and you can simply use it by adding the gtest files to your project's file structure.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestions, but I have written tests in cppunit which is a bunch of code and will take too much time to convert it to gtest. Will try Google C++ and gtest both for some other project.

Comment: No problem. Btw gtest is just the short name for Google C++ Testing Framework. :)

Comment: I want to ask one more thing here is that, Can we register more than one fixture in suite? like here in my code 

CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(MainTestFixture);
so, can I add on more line like this and run suite at once?

Comment: Frankly I'm not that familiar with CppUnit. In gtest you can use as many fixtures as you want: https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Test_Fixtures:_Using_the_Same_Data_Configuration_for_Multiple_Te

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not. Addition() is callback which will be registered in CPPUNIT engine and called by the driver - therefore it should use void(void) interface. Instead you could define your parameters as MainTestFixture's members.

```
class MainTestFixture : public TestFixture
{
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(MainTestFixture);    
    CPPUNIT_TEST(Addition);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(Multiply);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

public: 
    void setUp(void);
    void tearDown(void);
protected:
    // Test Functions 
    void init_fixture();
    void Addition(void);
    void Multiply(void);
protected: 
    //data members
    param1_t m_param1;
    param2_t m_param2;

};

void MainTestFixture::init_fixture()
{
     m_param1 = ...;
     m_param2 = ...;
}
void MainTestFixture::Addition()
{
    param1_t res= m_param1 + ...;
    // CPPUNIT_ASSERT(condition);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show with example of what you mean by "you could define your parameters as MainTestFixture's members"?

Comment: I want to ask one more thing here is that, Can we register more than one fixture in suite? like here in my code 

CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(MainTestFixture);
so, can I add on more line like this and run suite at once?